# Como renomear uma arquivo com a classe File da lib java.io?

Tags: java

Estou com dificuldade para entender o que realmente o método `.renameTo();` faz.
Segue o exemplo:

```
File arquivo = new File("caminho/nomeAtual.txt");

System.out.println(arquivo.getName());
arquivo.renameTo(new File("caminho/novoNome.txt"));
System.out.println(arquivo.getName());
```

Por qual motivo eu preciso colocar o `new`? O método cria uma cópia do conteúdo do arquivo e sobreescreve o mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Java você não trabalha diretamente com arquivos, e sim com abstrações que representam esses arquivos, que é o caso do objeto `File`. O `new` serve
só para instanciar a abstração, mas não vai fazer nada com o arquivo em si, não vai copiá-lo nem renomeá-lo a não ser que você chame comandos para realizar essas tarefas, como é o caso do `renameTo()`. Portanto não se preocupe com ele.

O `renameTo()` nesse caso apenas muda o nome do arquivo de `nomeAtual.txt` para `novoNome.txt`.

O uso do `renameTo()` no seu exemplo está correto, conforme mostra [este outro exemplo](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_renameto.htm).

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas a necessidade de precisar de dois `File` deve ter a ver com o próprio `renameTo()`. De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)), essa operação de renomear pode não ser bem-sucedida por uma variedade de razões, então o uso de um único objeto `File` não é suficiente para lidar com a situação.